# Location of the largest and smallest number in an array

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I can't figure out how I can get the index location of the largest and smallest numbers in an array. Someone who can help me out here?
My code:

```
int[] array = {4, 2, 7, 6, -3, -1, -2, 42, 0, -42, 9, -4, 5, -5, -6, -7, -8, -99, 42, 11, 20, 1, 2, 3};

 int smallest = array[0];
 int largest = array[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){

            if (array[i] > largest) {

                largest = array[i];

            } else if (array[i] < smallest)

                smallest = array[i];
            
        }
        System.out.println("Largest: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + smallest);
```

I have already the largest and smallest numbers, but how can I find the index locations.

Comment: What do you think `i` would give you?

Comment: You need to not only remember `largest` and `smallest` but at the same time where you store those also store a `indexOfLargest = i;` and `indexOfLowest = i;`.

Comment: Just write the index location into `largest` and `smallest`. Then when printing out your result you can retrieve the smallest and largest value from the array by using your saved index locations.

Answer (score 2):

Create two more variables to store Largest index and smallest index, now whenever you assign a new value to smallest and largest in if-else statements also assign the value of i.

```
int smallestInd = 0;
int largestInd = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){

            if (array[i] > largest) {

                largest = array[i];
                largestInd = i;

            } else if (array[i] < smallest)

                smallest = array[i];
                smallestInd = i;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
    int[] array = {4, 2, 7, 6, -3, -1, -2, 42, 0, -42, 9, -4, 5, -5, -6, -7, -8, -99, 42, 11, 20, 1, 2, 3};

    int si, smallest = array[si = 0];
    int li, largest = array[li = 0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > largest) {
            largest = array[li = i];
        } else if (array[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = array[si = i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest: " + li);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + si);
```

or easier readable:

```
    int[] array = {4, 2, 7, 6, -3, -1, -2, 42, 0, -42, 9, -4, 5, -5, -6, -7, -8, -99, 42, 11, 20, 1, 2, 3};

    int si = 0, smallest = array[0];
    int li = 0, largest = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > largest) {
            largest = array[i];
            li = i;
        } else if (array[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = array[i];
            si = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest: " + li);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + si);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    I was able to came up with two answers : 
    ary.sort();
    console.log(
  `This is max ${ary[0]} of the numbers and here is ${
    ary[-1]
  } the min of the numbers list!`
);
_________________________________________________________________
`   let ary = [8, 13, 2, 5, 44, 1, 5, 55];
    let max = ary[0];
    let min = ary[0];
    let locationMax, locationMin;
    for (i = 0; i <= ary.length; i++) {
      if (ary[i] > max) {
        max = ary[i];
        locationMax = i;
      } else if (ary[i] < min) {
        min = ary[i];
        locationMin = i;
      }
    }
    console.log(
      `This is the location of the max ${locationMax} so The second location number ${locationMin} is for min!`
    );
```

Comment: That’s not Java.